# Encrypt 3DES on oracle, decrypt doesn't work on DB2

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql, db2, 3des

I need to encrypt data on oracle and decrypt on DB2.

I can use only DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT on oracle.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    L_TEXT       VARCHAR2(16) := '1234567890123456';
    U_ID         VARCHAR2(16) := 'asdfghjk12345678';
    L_ENCRYPTED  VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN

DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DES3ENCRYPT(INPUT => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(L_TEXT),
                                     KEY => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(U_ID),
                                     ENCRYPTED_DATA => L_ENCRYPTED);
dbms_output.put_line(L_ENCRYPTED);
END;

OUTPUT: 9E2CC8BFE31C23189D16A6D4E946DF2E
-----------------------------------------------
select decrypt_char(CAST('9E2CC8BFE31C23189D16A6D4E946DF2E' AS VARBINARY(1000)), 'asdfghjk12345678')  from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

OUTPUT: ExampleExceptionFormatter: exception message was: [SQ20146] The decryption function failed.  The data is not encrypted.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you think this would work?  I suspect decrypt_char will only work on data that was encrypted by Db2 ENCRYPT_TDES function. You could verify this by running the Db2 ENCRYPT_TDES on the same data with same key, and comparing the outputs...

Answer (score 2):

`DES3ENCRYPT` sounds like it uses DES3.

`DECRYPT_CHAR` on DB2 (which is Deprecated BTW) can "can only decrypt values that are encrypted using the ENCRYPT function"

The ENCRYPT encryption algorithm is "RC2 block cipher with padding"

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004210.html